# In Revelation 21:8 Did John mean by "all liars" the previously mentioned in the same verse?

Tags: revelation

Revelation 21:8 (KJV);

> 8. But the fearful, and unbelieving, and the abominable, and murderers, and whoremongers, and sorcerers, and idolaters, and **all liars**, shall have their part in the lake which burneth with fire and brimstone: which is the second death.

Did John mean by **all liars** the previously mentioned in the same verse, i.e: the fearful, unbelieving, abominable, murderers...etc?

I mean that **all liars** not the eighth category, but includes the previously mentioned seven categories.

And if so, how a murderer be a liar?!, How a whoremonger be a liar?!

I hope you understood what I mean.

And why the last of the Bible (Revelation) condemn lying?, Look Revelation 21:8,27 and 22:15.

Comment: There are eight categories there. I don't understand why you want to make it seven plus a heading.

Comment: @NigelJ  He seems to be asking/not sure if "all liars" is an eighth category (since that's the only one with the word "all"). If so, then how "a murderer be a liar?!"

Comment: @JohnMartin It is my own supposition/interpretation (but I cannot prove it so cannot answer fully) that John is making it clear there are no 'white' lies. All liars, not just a selection of liars, will be condemned. Few would justify a murderer or whoremonger, but many justify the telling of (some) lies. So the addition of 'all' only relates to the eighth category, not the previous seven. In my view. But it is a good question and I have up-voted to cancel out the down-vote.And I have retracted my previous close vote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Peace.

The group which will have their part in the lake which burns with fire and brimstone are people who profess to know God but yet will not do His commandments.   They profess to know God but deny Him with their works.

> Titus 1: (16)  ***They profess that they know God; but in works they deny
>   him, being abominable,*** and disobedient, and unto every good work
>   reprobate.

All “liars” would indeed cover the other 7 categories of people written in Revelation 21.

The liars who profess to know God will not overcome and do His commandments so as to be found His sons and daughters .

Instead, they show that they do not know the Father nor the Son by the works that they will do.

> Revelation 21:7-8 KJV (7)  ***He that overcometh shall inherit all
>   things; and I will be his God, and he shall be my son.*** (8)  **But the
>   fearful, and unbelieving, and the abominable, and murderers, and
>   whoremongers, and sorcerers, and idolaters, and all liars,** shall have
>   their part in the lake which burneth with fire and brimstone: which is
>   the second death.

A “liar” is defined  as those who say they know God but yet will not keep His commandments.   When they say they “know God” and yet do not do His commandments, they show they really don’t know Him.

> 1 John 2:3-4 KJV (3)  *And hereby we do know that we know him, if we
>   keep his commandments. (4)  **He that saith, I know him, and keepeth not
>   his commandments, is a liar, and the truth is not in him**.*

If a man says “I love God” and yet hates his brother, then he is a liar as he does not do the commandment of God:  he that loves God is to love his brother also.

> 1 John 4:20-21 KJV (20)  ***If a man say, I love God, and hateth his
>   brother, he is a liar:*** for he that loveth not his brother whom he hath
>   seen, how can he love God whom he hath not seen? (21)  **And this
>   commandment have we from him, That he who loveth God love his brother
>   also.**

Again, the “liar” is saying that “I know God” but will not keep His commandments.

For example, they sought to kill Jesus who told them the Truth and did not keep God’s saying to have love for your brothers (like Cain who hated his brother Abel did not follow God’s instruction to “do well”).

> John 8:54-55 KJV (54)  *Jesus answered, If I honour myself, my honour
>   is nothing: it is my Father that honoureth me; of whom ye say, that he
>   is your God: (55)  **Yet ye have not known him; but I know him: and if I
>   should say, I know him not, I shall be a liar like unto you: but I
>   know him, and keep his saying**.*

A “murderer” is defined as those that hate their brothers.   Just by hating a brother is being a “murder” and is a “liar” for such people say they know God whom they have not seen but hate their brothers whom they have seen.

> 1 John 3:14-15 KJV (14)  *We know that we have passed from death unto
>   life, because we love the brethren. He that loveth not his brother
>   abideth in death. (15)  **Whosoever hateth his brother is a murderer:**
>   and ye know that no murderer hath eternal life abiding in him.*

They hated Jesus their brother whom they had seen and whom had told them the Truth which was heard of God.

> John 8:39-43 KJV (39)  *They answered and said unto him, Abraham is our
>   father. Jesus saith unto them, I**f ye were Abraham's children, ye would
>   do the works of Abraham.***

They sought to “kill” Jesus and was not one of Abraham’s children as they did not practice brotherly love and practiced hospitality **like Abraham did when the 3 messengers came to his tent** to tell him the truth.   (Genesis 18).

They did not believe Jesus who was sent by God nor His message nor did they do God’s commandments. They did not let brotherly love continue nor did they entertain the Stranger in their midst nor did receive His words of life and spirit. Their own hatred of Him caused them not to understand His words.

If God was their Father, then they would have loved Jesus.

> (40)  ***But now ye seek to kill me, a man that hath told you the truth,
>   which I have heard of God: this did not Abraham.*** (41)  Ye do the deeds
>   of your father. Then said they to him, We be not born of fornication;
>   we have one Father, even God. (42)  **Jesus said unto them, If God were
>   your Father, ye would love me:** for I proceeded forth and came from
>   God; neither came I of myself, but he sent me. (43)  Why do ye not
>   understand my speech? even because ye cannot hear my word.

The liars all will say that they know Him:  “Lord,  Lord” but will not do the will of the Father which is in Heaven...thereby demonstrating that  they do not know the Father nor the Son.

> Matthew 7:19-23 KJV (19)  ***Every tree that bringeth not forth good
>   fruit is hewn down, and cast into the fire.*** (20)  Wherefore by their
>   fruits ye shall know them. (21)  **Not every one that saith unto me,
>   Lord, Lord,** shall enter into the kingdom of heaven; **but he that doeth
>   the will of my Father which is in heaven.**

The Lord comes to give us an understanding.  He sends out His servants as messengers of His words of life and spirit to the churches.   Those who have an ear are to hear what the Spirit is saying to them.

Yet, MANY  who profess to know God will reject what is being said through the Spirit of Truth and will be found working evil  (like Diotrephes) as they will cast out the “devils”…their brothers that they label as such… who will tell them the Truth and will do those things (their supposed "wonderful works") that do not please God.

And while they will do these things, they will believe that they are doing God “service” in His name….doing evil works supposedly in God’s authority.  This is loving and practicing of the Lie of the serpent.

> (22)  *Many will say to me in that day, Lord, Lord, have we not
>   prophesied **in thy name?** and **in thy name have cast out devils?** and in
>   **thy name** done many wonderful works?*

They profess they know God and yet will not do what He says.   Jesus professes unto those who will  persist to work iniquity when someone will tell them the Truth:   “I never knew you”.

> (23)  And then will **I profess unto them, I never knew you:** depart from
>   me, ye that work iniquity.

They….the group that will have their part in the lake that burns with fire and brimstone…will cast out their brothers (whom they will hate) out of their church gatherings (synagogues = gatherings) and will “kill” as they will label those who will tell them the Truth as “devils” and all the while thinking that they are doing God “service”  (supposedly in His name/authority) for their “wonderful works” that are really evil works motivated by their hatred of their brothers.

> John 16:1-3 KJV (1)  *These things have I spoken unto you, that ye
>   should not be offended. (2)  They shall put you out of the synagogues:
>   yea, the time cometh, **that whosoever killeth you will think that he
>   doeth God service.***

They will do these things supposedly in His name but show that they do not really know the Father nor the Son that is sent to give them an understanding so that they may know Him who is true.

> (3)  **And these things will they do unto you, because they have not
>   known the Father, nor me.**

The “man of the sin” who exalts himself …who loves to be first among the churches…will not receive one who will come along to tell them the Truth that was heard.

> 3 John 1:9-12 KJV (9)  I wrote unto the church: but Diotrephes, who
>   loveth to have the preeminence among them, **receiveth us not.**

He  (like Diotrephes) will not receive those brothers…. “strangers”….as he will not practice brotherly love and entertain them and their words and will forbid that his congregation follow after him in his evil works towards those brothers who will be sent by Him to speak to the churches in the Spirit of Truth.

> (10)  ***Wherefore, if I come, I will remember his deeds which he doeth,***
>   prating against us with malicious words: and not content therewith,
>   neither doth he himself receive the brethren, and forbiddeth them that
>   would, **and casteth them out of the church**.

A “whoremonger” are those who will stay attached to those who love to be first and support the evil that will be done even after being told that “he that does good is of God” and “he that does evil has not seen God”..they don't know God.

> (11)  ***Beloved, follow not that which is evil, but that which is good.
>   He that doeth good is of God: but he that doeth evil hath not seen
>   God.*** (12)  Demetrius hath good report of all men, and of the truth
>   itself: yea, and we also bear record; and ye know that our record is
>   true.

We are not to keep company with those who are covetous…those who love to be first among us.  The “whoremonger” will stay put in their gatherings/churches and not come out from among them as directed after the hearing of the Truth.

They say they know God but will not do this:  “come out from among them and be separate and touch not the unclean ”.

Do not attach yourself any longer to the unclean gatherings of people who gather supposedly in His name and yet do not do His commandments.

The "unbelievers" in Revelation 21  will not believe in what they will hear the Spirit of Truth saying in this coming time and will continue their “business as usual” in their church gatherings and will have their part in the lake of fire. Just as Lot...we must come out from among them or suffer with them.

> 2 Corinthians 6:14-18 KJV (14)  ***Be ye not unequally yoked together
>   with unbelievers:*** for what fellowship hath righteousness with
>   unrighteousness? and what communion hath light with darkness? (15) 
>   And what concord hath Christ with Belial? or what part hath he that
>   believeth with an infidel? (16)  And what agreement hath the temple of
>   God with idols? for ye are the temple of the living God; as God hath
>   said, I will dwell in them, and walk in them; and I will be their God,
>   and they shall be my people. (17)  **Wherefore come out from among them,
>   and be ye separate, saith the Lord, and touch not the unclean thing;
>   and I will receive you, (18)  And will be a Father unto you, and ye
>   shall be my sons and daughters, saith the Lord Almight**y.

It will be business as usual in their gatherings…marrying their church doctrines….eating and drinking together…..

> Matthew 24:37-39 KJV (37)  *But as the days of Noe were, so shall also
>   the coming of the Son of man be. (38)  For as in the days that were
>   before the flood **they were eating and drinking, marrying and giving in
>   marriage,** until the day that Noe entered into the ark, (39)  And knew
>   not until the flood came, and took them all away; **so shall also the
>   coming of the Son of man be.***

In their gatherings, they will not keep the feast of unleavened brotherly love when one who is sent by Him to speak His words to their gatherings.

We must not eat with them ….following after their evil example when the Son of man comes to give us an understanding by the opening up of the Scriptures (the interpretation of them in Christ).

> 1 Corinthians 5:7-13 KJV (7)  Purge out therefore the old leaven, that
>   ye may be a new lump, as ye are unleavened. For even Christ our
>   passover is sacrificed for us: (8)  Therefore let us keep the feast,
>   not with old leaven, neither with the leaven of malice and wickedness;
>   but with the unleavened bread of sincerity and truth. (9)  I wrote
>   unto you in an epistle not to company with fornicators: (10)  Yet not
>   altogether with the fornicators of this world, or with the covetous,
>   or extortioners, or with idolaters; for then must ye needs go out of
>   the world. (11)  **But now I have written unto you not to keep company,
>   if any man that is called a brother be a fornicator, or covetous, or
>   an idolater, or a railer, or a drunkard, or an extortioner; with such
>   an one no not to eat.** (12)  For what have I to do to judge them also
>   that are without? do not ye judge them that are within? (13)  But them
>   that are without God judgeth. Therefore put away from among yourselves
>   that wicked person.

Answer (score 2):

From what I see, he is just listing the types of sinners that will be thrown into the lake of fire. He's not referencing back, but rather just also saying liars.

Lying is a sin that is deceptive and goes against the truth and against God. That is why Revelation condemns it.

Answer (score 1):

I believe john mentions all the liars in 1 john. I think its those who dont believe in the right Jesus. Who dont believe he came in the flesh, who dont believe he was the christ, who dont believe he lived a perfect life etc....

Answer (score 1):

I’m wondering about professing Christians, who are liars such as narcissist, that lie about people on turn others away from them because of their lies.
I believe in once saved always saved, so can Christians lie and cheat and steal, etc. and still go to heaven? I’ve always assumed that they can but I don’t understand why they would.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/47610)

Answer (score 1):

John was not writing a law book to tell what were sins. He just quoted some common types of sins most people committed. To those who meet their second death, certainly not limited to these eight categories. Actually we should always refer sins back to day one, on that day God declared His ten commandments.

- the fearful and unbelieving people committed the 1st commandment 'You shall have no other Gods before me
- the abominable people is likely referring to worship idol; committed the 2nd commandment
- murderers committed the 6th commandment
- whoremongers committed the 7th commandment
- sorcerers committed the 3th commandment, who take the name of the Lord thy God in vain
- idolaters worship idols committed the 2nd commandment
- Liars give false testimony committed the 9th commandment

Therefore these categories had not covered all the possible sins but it was not John's purpose to list everything. The believers of Jesus would know all sins because the Holy Spirit will tell them the truth.